# Some snap apps are not using the default theme (yaru) in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: themes, snap, 22.04

After the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, some of the apps installed as snap are having issues with the default theme (in any of its color variants). For instance, Retroarch, Ubuntu Store and Firefox can not use the default theme. Each of them use their own style (screenshot below). Curiously, the Spotfy (also snap) is ok. So I don't know what is happening at all.

I tried removing gtk-common-themes, then installed it again, but after that nothing changed. Any help?

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: You removed and reinstalled 'gtk-common-themes'. Can you be more specific how you did that?

Comment: I did run "snap remove gtk-common-themes" and then "snap install gtk-common-themes" on the terminal.

Comment: That is a good clarification that actually belongs to your question to remove any doubts: use "edit" to incorporate your comment in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

1. Uninstall gtk-common-themes using: `sudo snap remove gtk-common-themes`
2. Reinstall it again with: `sudo snap install gtk-common-themes --channel=latest/candidate` (`latest/beta` and `latest/edge` should also work)
3. reboot your session/re-login

The problem seemed to be that while the new installs shipped with version 0.1-79 of gtk-common-themes, if you upgraded from previous Ubuntu versions you still had stable version 0.1-59 from September 2021 which didn't have the necessary commits (dated from March 2022). Using `--channel=latest/candidate`
forces snap to install the newer version from candidate channel.

Comment: Hello dude. Thank you for the answer, it worked! Retroarch is the only app that's still using the wrong window decoration (it remains the same of the screenshot). It may be a retroarch specific issue, however I can live with that since I use it seldom.

Comment: I have the version `0.1-81` already installed and I'm getting the notification.