# Ubuntu software in 22.04 store does not use system theme

Tags: software-center, themes, snap, snap-store

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and the Ubuntu software store doesn't follow the applied system theme (or any other snap app fot that matter).

I wasn't using the default Ubuntu theme before this behavior was normal to me. But now, on 22.04, I started using the default theme so I expected the app conform to the selected appearance setting but, no matter if I choose the light or dark theme, the software store uses the default Adwaita theme.

Is this normal or am I missing something?

Comment: It is not normal, but I cannot reproduce that on a freshly installed 22.04 - there, it behaves as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some snap apps are not using the default theme (yaru) in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404650/some-snap-apps-are-not-using-the-default-theme-yaru-in-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm
I have the same issue.
The following command fixed it:

`sudo snap refresh --candidate gtk-common-themes`

I need to use the candidate channel for the gtk-common-themes package, when reverting back to the stable channel for gtk-common-themes i get the old ubuntu 21.10 theme again.