# Application theme and icon theme not working in applications

Tags: gnome, 22.04, icons, themes

Applications are not following application theme and icons are also all messed up. [Screenshot of applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64cWV.jpg)
The shell theme is working fine and the fonts are fine too. I ran the following code yesterday, I'll paste it because it might be causing it, although I'm not so sure about it.

```
for i in $(snap connections | grep gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes | awk '{print $2}'); do sudo snap connect $i orchis-themes:gtk-3-themes; done
```

I also reinstalled gtk-common-theme from snap like in the solution of this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404650/some-snap-apps-are-not-using-the-default-theme-yaru-in-ubuntu-22-04?rq=1).

[System information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfTAI.png)

Comment: Your icons may be "messed up" because you enabled "High contrast" in Accessibility settings. Solve that first.

Comment: I don't remember voluntarily changing to high contrast... but i cleaned the configs and rebooted (had to reapply all configs :'])